# Printing with indentation in python

Tags: python, word-wrap

is there a way to print the following,

```
print user + ":\t\t" + message
```

so that lengthy messages that are wider than the length of the terminal always wraps (starts from the same position) ?
so for example this

```
Username:              LEFTLEFTLEFTLEFTLEFTLEFTLEFT
RIGHTRIGHTRIGHT
```

should become

```
Username:              LEFTLEFTLEFTLEFTLEFTLEFTLEFT
                       RIGHTRIGHTRIGHT
```

Comment: You might want to use a longer example, because this one won't actually wrap on a typical 80-column terminal…

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I think what you're looking for here is the [`textwrap`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/textwrap.html) module:

```
user = "Username"
prefix = user + ": "
preferredWidth = 70
wrapper = textwrap.TextWrapper(initial_indent=prefix, width=preferredWidth,
                               subsequent_indent=' '*len(prefix))
message = "LEFTLEFTLEFTLEFTLEFTLEFTLEFT RIGHTRIGHTRIGHT " * 3
print wrapper.fill(message)
```

This prints:

```
Username: LEFTLEFTLEFTLEFTLEFTLEFTLEFT RIGHTRIGHTRIGHT
          LEFTLEFTLEFTLEFTLEFTLEFTLEFT RIGHTRIGHTRIGHT
          LEFTLEFTLEFTLEFTLEFTLEFTLEFT RIGHTRIGHTRIGHT
```

---

If you actually want to use tabs in the indent, that's a little trickier, because you have to first tab-expand the `initial_indent` to figure out the correct `subsequent_indent` to use. And, because your prefix actually *ends* with two tabs, it's even more complicated. Here's the simplest I've come up with:

```
user = "Username"
prefix = user + ":\t\t"
expanded_indent = textwrap.fill(prefix+'$', replace_whitespace=False)[:-1]
subsequent_indent = ' ' * len(expanded_indent)
wrapper = textwrap.TextWrapper(initial_indent=prefix,
                               subsequent_indent=subsequent_indent)
message = "LEFTLEFTLEFTLEFTLEFTLEFTLEFT RIGHTRIGHTRIGHT " * 3
print wrapper.fill(message)
```

If you do this repeatedly, you will probably want to wrap that mess up in a function.

Comment: And when his console is not of width 70?

Comment: @Hyperboreus The OP can pick the width they want to wrap on, and specify the `width` argument to `textwrap.TextWrapper`.

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr: +1. The reason it defaults to 70 is that this is a de facto standard (well, 70 or 71… it's not a very _strict_ standard) for wrapping when you don't know, or don't want to know, the target.

Comment: OK, so what do I do when I want to fit to my actual terminal width?

Comment: @Hyperboreus: You need to get your actual terminal width, maybe subtract 1, and pass that as the width. And you'd better write fallback code for the case where stdout isn't a terminal (e.g., it's redirected to a text file, or piped to some other program that may or may not be outputting to a console, or running as a WSGI…), or you just can't get the width. There's no all-purpose solution to this; you have to write what's appropriate to your use case.

Comment: @Hyperboreus The OP never asked about fitting to the terminal width. Just how to fit it to a given width.

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr: By the way, after years of stagnation, `textwrap` is getting a lot of attention recently. There's some new features in 3.4, and proposals for more in 3.5, so if there's any functionality you'd like to see added, now is the perfect time to get on python-ideas and suggest it.

Answer (score 22):

**In Python 2,** I suggest using [format](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) to indent left e.g.:

```
print '{:<30}{:<40}'.format('UserName:','Foo')
print '{:<30}{:<40}'.format('User:','FooBar')
print '{:<30}{:<40}'.format('','FooBar42')
```

will result to:

```
UserName:                     Foo                                     
User:                         FooBar                                  
                              FooBar42
```

And so on...

**For Python 3,** use parentheses :)
Also, the same can be written more compact using the [f-strings](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/):

```
print (f"{'UserName:':<30}{'Foo':<40}")
print (f"{'User:':<30}{'FooBar':<40}")
print (f"{'':<30}{'FooBar42':<40}")
```

will also result to:

```
UserName:                     Foo                                     
User:                         FooBar                                  
                              FooBar42
```

Answer (score 11):

You can use [**`str.ljust()`**](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.ljust) to pad out each line to the required width like so:

```
line_width = 20
print "Username:".ljust(line_width) + "LEFT"*6
print "".ljust(line_width) + "RIGHT"*3
```

The argument you pass to `ljust` is the length you wish the string to be, as long as this is consistant the lines should line up correctly.

Alternately, you can use string multiplication on lines where you just need the paddding like so:

```
print " "*line_width + "RIGHT"*3
```

This will have the exact same output as the last line in the above code.

Comment: Thanks a lot but not really what I was looking for. The LEFTLEFTRIGHT stuff is whats in the message variable, which changes all the time so I have no clue how lengthy it is.

Answer (score 1):

you can also use this format:
let's say you have the data frame df that you want to print all of it with an indentation.

```
print("\t"+df.to_string().replace("\n","\n\t"))
```

should work like magic