# How to print a little space after a every new line in python

Tags: python

I am trying to print a string.

currently it prints like this: `print("\t" + errorstr)`

```
       HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=10248): Max retries exceeded with url: /healthz 

(Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f9a92d5e6d0>: 

Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused',))
```

only for the first line the tab is being added.

then I tried:

```
print("\t"+u"{: ^32s}".format(errorstr))
```

but still it gives the same output.

How I want it to be is as follows:

```
     HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=10248): Max retries exceeded with url: /healthz 

     (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 
     0x7f9a92d5e6d0>: 

     Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused',))
```

The `tab` space should be included for each line. How can I do this in `python`?

**PS: I am using `python 2.7` for a reason, so I can't change the version and I WANT TO DO THIS WITH THE DEFAULT `python` packages, not any third-party libraries**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Printing with indentation in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18756510/printing-with-indentation-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

I'd try doing a string replacement to inject a tab in front of each new line: `print("\t" + errorstr.replace("\n", "\n\t"))`

Answer (score 1):

Your error string `errorstr` has multiple new line characters `\n` in it, you need to replace each new line character with a newline and a tab character `\t` as follows:

```
print("\t" + errorstr.replace("\n", "\n\t"))
```